# vba command to paste special KeepSourceFormatting(K) in powerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, paste

i am trying to take a cell range from excel and copy it to powerpoint2010. However I do not want to use the Embedded format but rather the KeepSourceFormatting one. I tried the following command

ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse

but this still creates an object that launches excel to edit the contents.

basically I want to paste a table of formated data from excel to powerpoint and maintain its appearance but still be able to edit the contents in powerpoint.

any ideas?

Comment: KazJaw's correct.  Another option, though ... an OLE object is essentially a metafile picture of the data you copied and the contents of the original (eg. Excel) file so that you can edit the data after activating it.  If you ungroup the OLE object, the data is tossed out, leaving you with just the metafile picture, which can then be ungrouped again if you wish to edit the component shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following options for `DataType`:

`ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` which allows edition each of separate field of the table (rather pure solution)

`ppPasteMetafilePicture` similar option

`ppPasteOLEObject`which you know

I can't see any other option.